# How to change the value to a global variable in the scope using a function? ("controller as")

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to change the value of the **this.usernamevalid** variable in the scope via a function called **checkusername**, this function is triggered from the view like this:

**register.jade:**
(ng-controller="controller as txt")

```
input(type="text", ng-model="formData.username",ng-blur="txt.checkusername('username',formData.username);" )
```

and the function **checkusername** is:

**regController.js**

```
 ngApp.controller('controller', Main );

    function Main(){
         //I need to set this variable to true;
         this.usernamevalid = false;




         //In the View, I trigger this function
        this.checkusername = function(param, val) {

            if (val != undefined) {
                $http.get('http://localhost:3000/users?param='+param+'&val='+val)
                .then(function(response){
                    var size = response.data.length;
                    switch (param) {
                        case 'username':
                            if (size>0) {
                                //The user exist (DOES NOT WORK)
                                this.usernamevalid = true;
                            } else {
                                //The user don't exist (DOES NOT WORK)
                                this.usernamevalid = false;
                            }
                            break;
                            default:
                                console.log('Field undefined, STOP');
                    }
                }, function(response){
                    alert(response + "(error)");
                });
            }


        }

}
```

I try using a callback function but the result was the same, I can't modify the result of **this.usernamevalid**, because "this is not defined".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically the `this` inside the `$http.get` function `.then` is not the same `this` of your controller context.

So you should create a variable in your controller function like below.

```
var vm = this;
```

Which will make your `this` context available everywhere in controller using `vm` variable.
Just replace `this` with `vm` wherever you have used `this`

**Code**

```
ngApp.controller('controller', Main);
   function Main() {
     var vm = this; //created local variable which will have this reference.
     //I need to set this variable to true;
     vm.usernamevalid = false;
     //In the View, I trigger this function
     vm.checkusername = function(param, val) {
       if (val != undefined) {
         $http.get('http://localhost:3000/users?param=' + param + '&val=' + val)
           .then(function(response) {
           var size = response.data.length;
           switch (param) {
             case 'username':
               if (size > 0) {
                 //The user exist (DOES NOT WORK)
                 vm.usernamevalid = true;
               } else {
                 //The user don't exist (DOES NOT WORK)
                 vm.usernamevalid = false;
               }
               break;
             default:
               console.log('Field undefined, STOP');
           }
         }, function(response) {
           alert(response + "(error)");
         });
       }
   }
 }
```

I'd highly recommend you to read up on [**this article**](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/)

Comment: what the advantage of using `this` instead of `$scope` please ?

Comment: @AlainIb there are two appraoches by which you can have controller. one is using `$scope` & the other one is using `this`(controllerAs) https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/ `controllerAs` is considered as better approach to having controller defined in that way.

Comment: ok thanks for the explanation and article. i will read about it and `var vm = this;`

Comment: @AlainIb please don't mix up two things..`controllerAs` is the way controller is defined. and `var vm= this;` is javascript scoping related concept..I've added one link at the end of mine answer..do look at that too..