# Login controller returns null values on post

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
myApp.controller('loginController',['$http', function($http)
{
    this.loginForm = function(){
        console.log(this.email); //prints undefined
        console.log(this.password); //prints undefined
        var encodedString = 'email=' +
                encodeURIComponent(this.email) +
                '&password=' +
                encodeURIComponent(this.password);
        $http({
            method:'POST',
            url: 'rs/loginResource',
            data: encodedString,
            headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        });
    };
}]);
```

Where `this.email` and `this.password` returns undefined.

My form:

```
<!-------------- loginController declared here (ERROR when declared)------------------->
<div class="row" ng-controller="loginController as loginCtrl"> 
<div class="col-md-12">
    Login via
    <div class="social-buttons">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-google" ><i class="fa fa-google"></i> Google</a>
    </div>
    or

    <!------------------------------------ Here is the form ---------------------------------------------------------->

    <form class="form" role="form" method="post" ng-submit="loginCtrl.loginForm()" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2" ng-model="loginCtrl.inputData.email">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email address" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2" ng-model="loginCtrl.inputData.password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password" required>
            <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="">Forget the password ?</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> keep me logged-in
            </label>
        </div>
    </form>

    <!------------------------------------ End of form ---------------------------------------------------------->
</div>
<div class="bottom text-center">
    New here ? <a href="#"><b>Join Us</b></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Tried printing it in console `console.log(this.email); console.log(this.password);` which prints `undefined` for both values. Is there any other way to capture values in angular

Comment: `this` inside the `$http.get` function is not the same of controller `this` http://stackoverflow.com/a/34474833/2435473

Comment: In your form you use `ng-model="loginCtrl.inputData.email"`. Try logging the `inputData` object.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you really want to work "scope free", I suggest you look into "TypeScript". It is really native to work with angular "scope free", with the "ControllerAs".

For your problem-->
First you use "inputData.email" & "inputData.password" but you call .email & .password.

After, you need to "drag" your this into the function, 
It will look something like this:

```
function loginController() {
                var _this = this;
                this.loginForm = function () {
                    console.log(_this.inputData.email);
                    console.log(_this.inputData.password);
                    var encodedString = 'email=' +
                        encodeURIComponent(_this.inputData.email) +
                        '&password=' +
                        encodeURIComponent(_this.inputData.email);
                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: 'rs/loginResource',
                        data: encodedString,
                        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
                    });
                };
```

Check out this link if you want to jump start angular+ typescript (I really recommend it!)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/888764/Getting-started-with-TypeScript-in-AngularJS-appli